# AWK - filter file with not equal fields

Tags: sed, awk

I've been trying to pull a field from a row in a file although each row may have plus or minus 2 or 3 fields per row.  They aren't always equal in the number of fields per row.

Here is a snippet:

```
A        orarpp 45286124        1     1   0 20  60   Nov 25  9-16:42:32    01:04:58 11176 117056      0   - oracleXXX (LOCAL=NO)
A        orarpp 45351560        1     1   3 20  61   Nov 30  5-03:54:42    02:24:48  4804 110684      0   - ora_w002_XXX
A        orarpp 45548236        1     1  22 20  71   Nov 26  8-19:36:28    00:56:18 10628 116508      0   - oracleXXX (LOCAL=NO)
A        orarpp 45679190        1     1   0 20  60   Nov 28  6-23:42:20    00:37:59 10232 116112      0   - oracleXXX (LOCAL=NO)
A        orarpp 45744808        1     1   0 20  60 10:52:19    23:08:12    00:04:58 11740 117620      0   - oracleXXX (LOCAL=NO)
A          root 45810380        1     1   0 --  39   Nov 25  9-19:54:34    00:00:00   448   448      0   - garbage
```

In the case of the first line, I'm interested in 9-16:42:32 and the similar fields for each row.

I've tried to pull it by using ':' as the field separator and then filter from there however, what I am trying to accomplish is to do something if the number before the dash (in the example it's 9) is greater than one.

```
cat file.txt | grep oracle | awk -F: '{print substr($1, length($1)-5)}'
```

This is because the number of fields on either side of the actual field I need can be different from line to line.

Definitely not the most efficient but I've been trying to do this with an awk one liner.

Hints or a direction would be appreciated to get me moving again. I am not opposed to doing in a better way than awk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do?

```
awk -F: '/oracle/ {print substr($0,62,10)}' file.txt
9-16:42:32
8-19:36:28
6-23:42:20
  23:08:12
```

This search for `oracle` and then print `10` characters starting from position `62`

Comment: This fits perfectly.  For some reason I didn't figure to notice field I was looking for started at character 61 no matter the number of fields in the files.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `cut` is the right tool for this job? For example, with your snippet:

```
$ cut -c 62-71 file.txt
9-16:42:32
5-03:54:42
8-19:36:28
6-23:42:20
  23:08:12
9-19:54:34
```

The arguments tell `cut` to snip columns (`-c`) 62 through 71.

For additional processing, you can pipe it to `awk`.

You can also accomplish the whole thing in `awk` by accepting entire lines and then using `substr` to extract the columns you want. For example, this `awk` command produces the same output as the `cut` command above:

```
awk '{ print substr($0, 62, 10) }' file.txt
```

Whether you create a pipeline or do the processing entirely in `awk` is at least in part a matter of personal taste / style.

Comment: This fits much like the one below.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab those identifiers with one of

```
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+-[[:digit:]]\{2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2\}'
grep -oP '\d+-\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'    # GNU grep
```

It sounds like you want to do something with the lines, not just find the ids. Please elaborate.

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk --re-interval '
    /oracle/ && \
    match($0, /([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]{2}:){2}[[:digit:]]{2}/, a) && \
    a[1]>1 {
        # do something with the matching line
        print
    }
' file
```

Comment: I should have mentioned gawk wasn't an option.  Not using a linux based system.